# Passing Iqueryable values to a user defined function in LinqToSql as input parameter

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
Var rettable=(from table1 in dao.table1s
    where table1.name="Question" Select table);
```

Now I need to pass this Iqueryable value to the Table valued user defined function and implement the sort based on the output.

```
Var rettable2=(from rettab in rettable
join x in dao.userdefinedfunction (rettable.col1)
on x.col1=rettable.col1 and x.col2=='S'
select new {x,rettable} order by x.col1
```

How can we achieve this kind of functionality?

Comment: Rewrite `userdefinedfunction` into a view and join the view with `rettable` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass to method Iqueryable, but you can pass it as a list

```
var rettable=(from table1 in dao.table1s
where table1.name="Question" Select table).ToList();
```

and then rettable can be passed to any method.

P.S. As array or List will work as well

Comment: The Problem is That list will be having millions of records.
If we try to enumerate, all this objects will be loaded to inmemory Which is not a good sign